# Windows network bridge: STP parameters

Tags: windows, bridge, stp, rstp

I recently discovered Windows 7 does support STP upon it's own Ethernet bridges. 
https://reggle.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/hidden-feature-in-windows-7-spanning-tree/

Although the feature is barely  documented by Microsoft, can this work practically without much configuration options? The only option I could find was a way to disable it (registry hack `DisableSTA`).

Do I have any choices with the windows Ethernet bridge when doing (R)STP and wanting to control—for example—the bridge priority. I couldn't even figure out what the STP default parameters of this bridge are?

Does anyone use STP with Windows Ethernet bridges?

Thank you!